# Trying to plot Fourier sines

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-science, fft

```
from matplotlib import markers
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [9,9]
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size' : 16})

#domain definition
dx = 0.01 #input("input the step size: ")
x = np.pi*np.arange(-1+ float(dx),1+float(dx),float(dx))
n = len(x)
nquart = int(np.floor(n/4))

#hat funtion
f = np.zeros_like(x)
f[nquart : 2*nquart] = (4/n)*np.arange(1,nquart+1)
f[2*nquart:3*nquart] = np.ones(nquart) - (4/n)*np.arange(0,nquart)

#subplot creation
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(x,f)

#core fourier series
name = 'accent'
cmap = get_cmap('tab10')
colors = cmap.colors
ax.set_prop_cycle(color = colors)

# sum of values with an array of ones with the same shape and type as a given array.
Ao = np.sum(f*np.ones_like(x))*dx
ffs = Ao/2

A = np.zeros(20)
B = np.zeros(20)

for k in range(20):
    #the inner products
    A[k] = np.sum(f*np.cos(np.pi*(k+1)*(x/np.pi)))*dx
    B[k] = np.sum(f*np.sin(np.pi*(k+1)*(x/np.pi)))*dx

    ffs = ffs + A[k]*np.cos((k+1)*np.pi*(x/np.pi)) + B[k]*np.sin((k+1)*np.pi*(x/np.pi))
    ax.plot(x,ffs,markers = 'o',LineWidth = 1.5)
    plt.show()
```

when running the code i get an error **AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property'markers ,'LineWidth'**
if i do not use the markers and LineWidth the code runs but the expected outcome is not what i wanted
*i am getting around 15 graphs but that is not what i wanted the color style is also not getting applied*

Comment: What is the reason you are adding an `s` to `marker=` and writing `linewidth=` with two upper case letters? See the [`ax.plot()` docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html).  You also might want to call `plt.show()` only once at the end, instead of continuously inside the `for` loop.

Comment: yess thank you so much for a sec i forgot about that ... i rectified thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'markers ,'LineWidth'

That's because it should be `marker` and `linewidth`:

With those changes, and taking `plt.show()` out of the loop:

```
for k in range(20):
    #the inner products
    A[k] = np.sum(f*np.cos(np.pi*(k+1)*(x/np.pi)))*dx
    B[k] = np.sum(f*np.sin(np.pi*(k+1)*(x/np.pi)))*dx

    ffs = ffs + A[k]*np.cos((k+1)*np.pi*(x/np.pi)) + B[k]*np.sin((k+1)*np.pi*(x/np.pi))
    ax.plot(x,ffs,marker = 'o',linewidth = 1.5)
    
plt.show()
```

...we obtain:
[image]